# SharePoint custom Callout menu adds Share, Delete & download button

Tags: sharepoint-online, download, share, callouts

I have documents links on html page once hover on that link I'm opening the document in callout menu

[image]

In the above image you can see that the default **Share, Delete & Download** options are not available.

I have to add the **Share, Downlaod and Delete options** at the bottom.

But I have tried to use the Share functionaliy of Doc lib, but its not working for me.

Below is the working code to open call out

```
        //Custom callout body section function
        function getCallOutFilePreviewBodyContent(urlWOPIFrameSrc, pxWidth, pxHeight) {
            var callOutContenBodySection = '<div class="js-callout-bodySection">';
            callOutContenBodySection += '<div class="js-filePreview-containingElement">';
            callOutContenBodySection += '<div class="js-frame-wrapper" style="line-height: 0">';
            callOutContenBodySection += '<iframe style="width: ' + pxWidth + 'px; height: ' + pxHeight + 'px;" src="' + urlWOPIFrameSrc + '&amp;action=interactivepreview&amp;wdSmallView=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
            callOutContenBodySection += '</div></div></div>';
            return callOutContenBodySection;
        }

        //call to callout manager class
        function OpenItemFilePreviewCallOut(sender, strTitle, urlWopiFileUrl) {
            RemoveAllItemCallouts();
            var openNewWindow = true; //set this to false to open in current window

            //choose the launch point HTML element 
            var callOutContenBodySection = getCallOutFilePreviewBodyContent(urlWopiFileUrl, 308, 254);
            var clg = CalloutManager.getFromLaunchPointIfExists(sender);

            if (clg == null) {
                //call the CalloutManager to create the callout
                clg = CalloutManager.createNewIfNecessary({
                    // configure options
                    ID: 'CalloutId_' + sender.id,
                    launchPoint: sender,
                    beakOrientation: 'topBottom',
                    title: strTitle,
                    content: callOutContenBodySection,
                });

                //Custom action 'Open'
                var customAction = new CalloutActionOptions();
                customAction.text = 'Open';
                //custom action event on click open
                customAction.onClickCallback = function(event, action) {
                    alert('open');
                    if (openNewWindow) {
                        window.open(urlWopiFileUrl);
                        RemoveItemCallout(sender);
                    } else {
                        window.location.href = urlWopiFileUrl;
                    }
                };

                var _newCustomAction = new CalloutAction(customAction);
                clg.addAction(_newCustomAction);

            }
            clg.open();
        }



        function RemoveAllItemCallouts() {
            CalloutManager.forEach(function(callout) {
                // remove the current callout
                CalloutManager.remove(callout);
            });
        }

        function RemoveItemCallout(sender) {
            var callout = CalloutManager.getFromLaunchPointIfExists(sender);
            if (callout != null) {
                // remove
                CalloutManager.remove(callout);
            }
        }

        function CloseItemCallout(sender) {
            alert();
            var callout = CalloutManager.getFromLaunchPointIfExists(sender);
            if (callout != null) {
                // close
                callout.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: might this link will help you. http://sharepoint-examples.blogspot.com/2015/06/adding-item-to-ecb-edit-control-block.html

Comment: Those are the customer actions.  I want OOB Share, Delete actions there